# Download images from an external source iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, retina-display

Is it possible to download images from a web server and save them in such a way that

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"filename"]
```

would still work for filename.png and filename@2x.png just as if they had been sent along in the application package all along?

Comment: imageNamed only works for files in the main app bundle

Comment: I guess the right thing to do would just be to get the current scale for the device, download the appropriate image, e.g. retina/non-retina and just load it from wherever you save it...

Comment: @Piotr, Why do you want both images in the same device? A device can be either retina or non-retina right? It would be better to download only one instead of two as downloading duplicate images will cause more bandwidth to be used. Instead you can pass the scale as a param to get the images.

Comment: @phix23 Actually, last I checked you could load images outside your app via a relative path (e.g. `"../Documents/foo.png"`). Dubious and not guaranteed to work, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer. You can try to send the scale based on retina/non-retina and then download a single image based on that. You dont need to worry about combining two images and downloading since a device can be either retina or non-retina only. You dont need both images at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the images based on retina/non-retina of the device itself. No need to keep both in the same device.

Answer (score 0):

As you are considering downloading both images, so bandwidth *per se* is not of concern, why not combine the two images into a multi-resolution TIFF and download that from the web server? If you do that and load the image from the file the correct resolution will be picked automatically.